Amcharts 5 Missing bar chart columns with clustered columns
I am using Amcharts 5 and I experience an anomoly when using clusterd column series. If I have more 4 or more clusters, some columns are not rendered, different columns for different clusters. Can not find any pattern. As you can see in the image attached the orange column is missing even if value is 30. 
Any one with takes on this?
Axis configuration looks like this (using typescript)
 const xRenderer = am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(this.root, {
  cellStartLocation: 0,
  cellEndLocation: 1,
  minorGridEnabled: false,
});

xRenderer.grid.template.setAll({
  location: 1
});

const xAxis = this.mainChart.xAxes.push(am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(this.root, {
  categoryField: 'entityLabel',
  renderer: xRenderer,
  tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(this.root, {})
}));

const yRenderer = am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(this.root, {
  strokeOpacity: 0.1
});

const yAxis = this.mainChart.yAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(this.root, {
  renderer: yRenderer,
  maxPrecision: 0,
  min: this.settings ? this.settings.minValue : 0,
  max: this.settings ? this.settings.maxValue : 100,
  numberFormat: `#${this.settings && this.settings.percentageValues ? "'%'" : ""}`,
  strictMinMax: true
}));

const series = this.mainChart.series.push(am5xy.ColumnSeries.new(this.root, {
    name: seriesConfig.label,
    xAxis: xAxis,
    yAxis: yAxis,
    valueYField: "displayValue",
    categoryXField: "entityLabel",
    sequencedInterpolation: false,
    tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(this.root, {
      labelText: `[bold]{dataItem.entity_alias}[/]\n{label}: [bold]{displayValue}[/]${ this.settings.percentageValues ? '%' : '' }`
    })
  }));

  series.columns.template.setAll({
    width: am5.percent(70)
  });


Above code looks correct to me as it is all about rendering the chart with its specific attributes to render X and Y axes and rendering respective data. What I can suggest is try sorting the actual data on X axis prior rendering them on the chart. That should work.
